# The method for_each exists but trait bounds not satisfied when using StreamDeckSocket

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the [streamdeck-rs](https://docs.rs/streamdeck-rs/0.3.0/streamdeck_rs/index.html) crate, and I'm having trouble getting the [example code](https://docs.rs/streamdeck-rs/0.3.0/streamdeck_rs/socket/struct.StreamDeckSocket.html) to work.

My implementation is basically the exact example given:

```
use futures::future::Future;
use std::env;
use streamdeck_rs::registration::*;
use streamdeck_rs::socket::StreamDeckSocket;

//the fields of these structs doesn't matter
struct GlobalSettings {}
struct ActionSettings {}
struct MessageToSd {}
struct MessageFromSd {}

fn register() {
    let params = RegistrationParams::from_args(env::args()).unwrap();
    let connect =
        StreamDeckSocket::<GlobalSettings, ActionSettings, MessageFromSd, MessageToSd>::connect(
            params.port,
            params.event,
            params.uuid,
        );
    tokio::run(
        connect
            .map_err(|e| println!("connection failed: {:?}", e))
            .and_then(|socket| {
                socket
                    .for_each(|message| println!("recieved: {:?}", message))
                    .map_err(|e| println!("read error: {:?}", e))
            }),
    );
}
```

My error message changes based on what I'm importing, but it's always a variant of "the method `for_each` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied". With the imports I listed now, my error message is:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `for_each` found for type `streamdeck_rs::socket::StreamDeckSocket<GlobalSettings, ActionSettings, MessageFromSd, MessageToSd>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:37:35
   |
37 |         .and_then(|socket| socket.for_each(|message| println!("recieved: {:?}", message))
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `for_each` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&mut streamdeck_rs::socket::StreamDeckSocket<GlobalSettings, ActionSettings, MessageFromSd, MessageToSd> : std::iter::Iterator`
```

---

I can import `future::Stream`:

```
use streamdeck_rs::registration::*;
use streamdeck_rs::socket::StreamDeckSocket;
use std::env;
use futures::future::Future;
use futures::Stream;
//rest same as before
```

And I get this error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `for_each` found for type `streamdeck_rs::socket::StreamDeckSocket<GlobalSettings, ActionSettings, MessageFromSd, MessageToSd>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:37:35
   |
37 |         .and_then(|socket| socket.for_each(|message| println!("recieved: {:?}", message))
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `for_each` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&mut streamdeck_rs::socket::StreamDeckSocket<GlobalSettings, ActionSettings, MessageFromSd, MessageToSd> : futures::stream::Stream`
           `&mut streamdeck_rs::socket::StreamDeckSocket<GlobalSettings, ActionSettings, MessageFromSd, MessageToSd> : std::iter::Iterator`
           `streamdeck_rs::socket::StreamDeckSocket<GlobalSettings, ActionSettings, MessageFromSd, MessageToSd> : futures::stream::Stream`



warning: unused import: `futures::Stream`
```

Note the warning about the unused import, too.

Because `StreamDeckSocket` is defined in the crate, I can't implement any traits on it.

I know this question exists in a few forms, but, from what I understand, those answers are only applicable if there is a missing trait implementation in the crate I'm using.

Comment: You definitely want the`for_each()` method from `futures::Stream`, so you need to bring that trait in scope. If this leads to further errors, please add them to the question, so we can figure out how to resolve them.

Comment: @SvenMarnach added more details about the `futures::Stream` errors

Comment: What versions of `streamdeck_rs` and `futures` are you using? From a quick look at the documentation, it appears that `StreamDeckSocket` should be implementing `Stream`.

Comment: Also note that some of your structs need to `#[derive(Deserialize)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code snippet isn't quite right, but very close:

- the structures need to `#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]`
- according to [the documentation](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.27/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.for_each), the closure passed to the `for_each` has the wrong type.

The following compiles:

```
use futures::future::Future;
use futures::stream::Stream;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::env;
use streamdeck_rs::registration::*;
use streamdeck_rs::socket::StreamDeckSocket;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct GlobalSettings {}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct ActionSettings {}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MessageToSd {}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MessageFromSd {}

fn main() {
    let params = RegistrationParams::from_args(env::args()).unwrap();
    let connect =
        StreamDeckSocket::<GlobalSettings, ActionSettings, MessageFromSd, MessageToSd>::connect(
            params.port,
            params.event,
            params.uuid,
        );
    tokio::run(
        connect
            .map_err(|e| println!("connection failed: {:?}", e))
            .and_then(|socket| {
                socket
                    .for_each(|message| {
                        println!("recieved: {:?}", message);
                        Ok(())
                    })
                    .map_err(|e| println!("read error: {:?}", e))
            }),
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more about the type on `for_each`? Does it need the actual return of `Ok())`? I'm still trying to learn how to read Rust type signatures.

Comment: @Max, certainly. Basically, [the documentation of `for_each`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.27/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.for_each) says it expects a closure of type `FnMut(Self::Item) -> U`, which accepts one parameter and returns something of type `U`. That `U` is a shorthand to `IntoFuture<Item = (), Error = Self::Error>`. [The `IntoFuture` type](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.27/futures/future/trait.IntoFuture.html) in turn says it either resolves to a value of type `Item` or to an error of type `Error`. In this case, `Item` is simply `()`. Hence the return of `Ok(())`.

Comment: That said, the rustc error message here is rather opaque and hard to parse. The diagnostics has room to improve. Fortunately, the rust-lang project already has [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54771)  to track the progress of said diagnostics.